# Impossible Question: High School Geometry

Tags: geometry

Using only facts about the angle sums of triangles, exterior angles theorem and vertical angles, is it possible to find the measure of all of these angles inside both triangles??
(No assumptions are "missing")
[image]

Comment: No. You could imagine sliding E along the line spanned by DE and it wouldn't change any of the measured angles.

Comment: On the other hand, if B, C, and E are meant to be colinear, and BAC a right angle, then yes.

Comment: "Vertical angles" - did you mean **right** angles? Is it assumed that both triangles are right-angled triangles, i.e. $\angle BAC=\angle DCE=90^\circ$?

Comment: There are no assumptions. Only what is labeled and that there are a couple of triangles. Vertical angles may not apply, but is known as a tool.

Comment: Please don't down vote it because you think that "assumptions are missing". It is designed intentionally to be unsolvable and to illicit false assumptions. I am testing it out.

Comment: @Zeta10: *"It is designed intentionally to be unsolvable and to illicit false assumptions. I am testing it out."* Please keep in mind that people visit Math.SE to help others, not to be "tested". You should therefore provide a clear indication what exactly your intentions are. Eg, "I'm trying to design an impossible question. Have I succeeded?" This will help people provide useful feedback without wasting time explaining things you already understand or second-guessing the stated assumptions in an unnecessary attempt to solve the problem. ... Good luck!

Comment: *elicit*, not *illicit*, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are right. It is not "illicit" at all. Thank you.

Comment: @Blue, if you feel my question is an example of unethical experimentation, please let me know. I have often felt that if an experiment can create negative affect intentionally, then it should be stated. Such as in AB testing that requires slower loading speeds. But, here I did say "Impossible Question"-- so, I will be more specific next time.

Comment: @Zeta10: Not "unethical", necessarily, but certainly "inconsiderate". Look at how much effort Prem *unnecessarily wasted* concocting and writing-up solvable variants of your question. The default mindset here is "Someone needs help solving the stated problem"; when your actual need is more "meta" than that, you should say so explicitly. ... BTW, I find the two words "Impossible Question" alone insufficient to convey your intent. A student could use the same two words to label a seemingly unfair question they'd been assigned and with which they legitimately need help to resolve. ... Cheers!

Comment: @Blue I think if Prem thought it was unnecessary, then they could have elected not to do it. I think you are really assuming too much to state that you understand the "default mindset". I think your assessment is incorrect and hypersensitive based on your own reaction, which you have generalized to the other users. Also, I do not think the question is unfair at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (1) Not Solvable :

We can not get the angles because there is not enough information.

[image: Not Solvable]

Here Point A can move & give variable angle BAC.
More-over, Point E can move & give variable angle DEC. [[ In continuation of the Comment by user "Cheerful Parsnip" ]]

### (2) Solvable :

We might make assumptions (or the Question might have assumptions which is missing in the Post ) & get various angles.

(2A) BAC is visually right angle.
(2B) C is on the line BE.
[[ Assumptions are in line with the comment by user "Arturo Magidin" ]]

Possible Solution:
ACB=180-54-90=36
DCE=180-108=72
CDE=360-312=48
DEC=180-72-48=60

(2C) AB=AC
(2D) CD=CE
[[ Visually, the 2 triangles are isosceles ]]

Possible Solution:
ACB=ABC=54
BAC=180-54-54=72
EDC=360-312=48
DEC=48
DCE=180-48-48=84

With some other assumptions , we will get some other Answers.

Comment: No assumptions are missing. You are correct. It is not solvable.

Comment: I want to make sure that it is actually unsolvable and that someone perhaps smarter and more familiar than me cannot solve it given only what is in the post.

Comment: It is "Not Solvable" with a "Pictorial Proof" ! I hope that it helps you in your teaching activity. UpVote +1 for your Question from my side , to "Negate" a DV.

Comment: Thanks @Prem because the students often make assumptions based on what the figure "looks like". I want them to learn that we cannot do so unless we explicitly given such an assumption.